# Is there a Ionicons: Icon props?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ionicons

So I am writing a functional component right, I written a props.
So I wanted it to able to auto suggest name attributes. Something like this

```
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export interface ownWrittenProps {
  leftIcon?: ????????;
}
```

so when people start typing  <FunctionalComponent  **leftIcon="** it can suggest the acceptable icon names from `Ionicons` the reason I want to use it because it pack into the ios/apk package anyway. What should I put in `????????` so that it can suggest the name?

Another question, if I have a textbox in my ChildComponent how do I retrieve the text/value from parent?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`@expo-vector-icons` exposes a glyphMap for each icon type. You can use this to generate the name suggestions.

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export interface ownWrittenProps {
  leftIcon?: keyof typeof Ionicons.glyphMap;
}
```

This will create a type from the map, then make sure that only keys of that type can be used when setting leftIcon.

Comment: omg you are awesome, thank you so much. Another question, if I have a textbox in my ChildComponent how do I retrieve the text/value from parent?

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If suggestions didn't work you can directly find icon name from [Ionicons](https://ionicons.com/) official website and use it like a component.

Example:

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

<Ionicons name="add-outline" size={24} color="black" />
```

or

```
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export interface ownWrittenProps {
  leftIcon?: "add-outline";
}
```

Comment: this is too painful to do if user who use your component need to add it